# Upgrade js file to use import

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

I'm trying to upgrade to use import instead of requires for modules:
My old code looked like so:

```
const { NETWORK } = require(`${basePath}/constants/network.js`);
```

The network.js File:

```
export const NETWORK = {
  eth: "eth",
  sol: "sol",
};

module.exports = {
  NETWORK,
};
```

When ever I try to import i've tried a few syntaxes):

```
import { NETWORK } from '../constants/network.js';
import NETWORK  from '../constants/network.js';
import * as NETWORK  from '../constants/network.js';
```

I get an error:

```
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '..\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///../constants/network.js:6:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:526:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)
```

When I try to rename the file to be network.cjs I get an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

how can I import variables from js files using import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the unnecessary "module.exports" part from your network.js, because that is [the way to export stuff in commonjs](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/). Your first line of import will work after that `import { NETWORK } from '../constants/network.js';` so remove the other ones